# iPhone Store Kit Testing

Tags: iphone

To test an in app purchase on the iphone, do I need to upload the binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to upload the binary, for anyone who was curious.  You do need to make sure all the contracts are in place, however.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [section](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/DevelopingwithStoreKit/DevelopingwithStoreKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH103-SW1) describing testing Store Kit process in documentation.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. I've found that section to have many errors.  For example to actually test it you shouldn't add your test user credentials in the store preferences, but unset them there, and then add the credentials after prompted within your app.